# Is it possible to group JSON fields into one property using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm wondering if there is any way to deserialize several JSON fields to just one Java property. E.g. given this JSON:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "name" : "Bartolo",
  "address" : "whatever",
  "phone" : "787312212"
}
```

deserialize it to this class:

```
public class Person {

    public String id;
    public String name:

    @JsonProperty(names = {"address", "phone"}) //something like this
    public String moreInfo;

}
```

so `moreInfo` equals to `"whatever, 787312212"` or something similar.

Is this possible *without using custom deserializer*?

Comment: you mean DEserialize?

Comment: @jhamon yes, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `@JsonCreator` annotation like following:

```
String json = {"id" : "1",  "name" : "Bartolo", "address" : "whatever", "phone" : "787312212" }

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person = mapper.readValue(json , Person.class);
```

and in the constructor of your Person class add this

```
@JsonCreator
public Person(@JsonProperty("address") String address, @JsonProperty("phone") String phone) {
    this.moreInfo = address + "," phone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you don't want to know/handle other fields in the object, but decided to still receive these fields (maybe for logging purposes), then you can put them in a key-value store(Map)

```
@Getter
private final Map<String, Object> otherFields = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, Object value) {
    otherFields.put(name, value);
}
```

Note that if you have any field with the same name as the Map field(like 'otherFields' in the example above), then you can get `MismatchedInputException`